# Inline installation not working and give me error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have some problem with inline-installation.
Although I do everything as stated in the documentation:
https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation
I get the error:
Uncaught No Chrome Web Store item link found.
My Plug-In: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/reestrunet/fnpnbpfgdnjilaogjljcdpggonogbdoc?hl=ru

```
<head>

    <link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fnpnbpfgdnjilaogjljcdpggonogbdoc">

</head>


<body>

    <button onclick="chrome.webstore.install()" id="install_plug">Install Plug-In!</button>

</body>
```

What's my wrong?

Comment: Is the webstore item already enabled for inline install?

Comment: Yes. I'm already edit my question.

Comment: Do you have an example page live we can look at?